# Ошибка при подключении выдвижного меню к пустому проекту

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Четкой и ясной инструкции как всегда нет. Пытаюсь прикрутить выдвигающиеся меню к пустому проекту, но сталкиваюсь с проблемой:

```
error: attribute menu (aka com.example.main_rfid_test:menu) not found.
```

Хотя в шаблоне проекта с выдвигающемся меню все сделано точно так же и оно работает. Не могу понять почему параметра нет у меня, зато есть у шаблона:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/navigate_menu.xml"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

navigate_menu находиться в директории menu.

bild.grad:
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

На картинке res, файл на месте, ничего не понимаю:

Comment: Видимо нужного файла в нужном месте нет. Проверьте ещё раз (и приложите скрин структуры проекта) что у вас нужный файл в нужно папке (`res/menu/`)

Comment: А может у вас библиотека какая-то не подключена. Покажите `Build.gradle`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Добавил

Comment: Я сравнил все билды и манифест шаблон с выдвижными меню и пустой проект.... Разницы никакой. Дело не в этом

Comment: Судя по этому (https://medium.com/quick-code/android-navigation-drawer-e80f7fc2594f) нужна библиотека `design`. Покажите `build.gradle` модуля - именно там библиотеки подключаются.

Comment: Также в DrawerLayout должны быть 2 вьюхи. Одна для собственно экрана, вторая - выдвижное меню. Отличаются они прописыванием `android:gravity="start"` (или `android:layout_gravity`) для меню.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Можете оформить это как ответ- это исправило конкретно эту проблему, признаю не доглядел нужной либы) Спасибо большое, вам)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае требуется подключить библиотеку `design`

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
//или версия из нового репозитория, если используется пакет `androidx`
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
```